# How to create a filter in website

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can a create a filter for showcase in website?
Kinda like categorising things.

I want to build a website with a showcase of my photo. However, I don't know how can I create a showcase with filter function, can anyone help?

Comment: So you want a gallery which shows pictures or text for a photo? I think i dont understand!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: like a search bar for given words in the images "headlines"?

Comment: Is your website CMS based or just html/css/js??

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft Nope, its like having different categories on the top of the showcase, Like all, Photography, Painting etc.
And I can click the category to filter out some of the item in the showcase

Comment: @dutchsociety just html/css/js

Comment: If I helped you out please vote my answer :)

Comment: @dutchsociety I did voted your answer but my reputation is too low to show my vote in public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched on the internet "categorizing filter with images" and found this JSFiddle. Hopefully it could help you.

It's using HTML and JavaScript.

See link: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ebrnj/

```
<ol id="controls">
    <li><a href="#" id="web">Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="canvas">Canvas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="print">Print</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="all">All</a></li>
</ol>
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png" class="web" />
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png" class="canvas" />
    <img src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/drPooh2.png" class="print" />
</div>

$('#controls li a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this,
            $that = $(that),
            id = that.id,
            gallery = $('#gallery');
        if (id == 'all') {
            gallery.find('img:hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else {
            gallery.find('img.' + id + ':hidden').fadeIn(1000);
            gallery.find('img').not('.' + id).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
```

Good luck!!, if you have some questions about this please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I use Isotope for sort my website in my portfolio. The concept is to set some category in my item's class, and with sort button I can display on wordpress website, or one-page website.

The framework => http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Ask if you need some helps to set it :p

Comment: It seems a good framework to work with (b) Thank you. i will check it out. But is there any native way to do so?

Comment: Basically you can do it faster with Angular and JQuery, but it's a bit hard for begginer so I let you to check some documentation of Angular : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy